# (Dojo) How set focus to same input, by using widgets dijit?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need set focus to input, by using widgets dijit. I don now how require property focus() in form._FormWidget.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true" >
</script>
<script>
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
dojo.require("dijit.form._FormWidget");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");    

var ws = new dijit.form._FormWidget();
ws.focus(dijit.byId("company"));
</script>

<input id="company" type="text" name="company" />
```

This not working! Pls help.

If use document.getElementById('company').focus(); i hav error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null.

Comment: `document.getElementById('company')` will only work after the document is loaded. You need to use `dojoi/ready` module e.g `require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready){document.getElementById('company').focus()});});`. see [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/ready.html#id4) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I get what you're asking, but if you're just looking to focus a simple native HTML input, just call `focus` on it directly, no Dojo or Dijit required.

```
document.getElementById('company').focus();
```

Dijit form widgets tend to have their own `focus` methods which will do the same thing for their own inputs.  You can't call `focus` on a Dijit widget for the purpose of focusing something other than the widget itself.

Meanwhile, `dijit.byId('company')` won't return anything on your page since the `company` input is *not* a Dijit widget.